# compatibility between nvidia driver and cuda

Tags: docker, pytorch, cuda, nvidia, libtorch

I have a RTX 4070 and it said nvidia-driver-535 is recommended.
and I installed the driver. but when I type nvidia-smi, it said CUDA version: 12.2
but I want to get CUDA 11.8 or 12.1

Question :

1. Should I only install recommended nvidia driver?
2. If so, can I install lower version of CUDA?
3. If not so, If I want to install CUDA 12.1, Should I install the nvidia-driver which has compatibility with CUDA 12.1 and My RTX 4070?

https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html

I've checked above document. but I am confused because I don't know if the driver has compatibility with my RTX4070 even though the driver has compatibility with the CUDA that I want to install.

**One more,** 
I am trying to install Docker. and Does the base machine's nvidia driver affect to docker cuda and cuDNN?(I think Of course it will affect. stupid question.)
I want to use CUDA 12.1 Ubuntu 20.04 Docker image so, Should I install nvidia driver which has compatibility with the image in base machine?

Thank you for reading my long question.
I am waiting for your messages..
I am struggling with this more than a week.

**(Tried)** 
I had changed docker image a lot with nvidia-driver-535 but pytorch(libtorch) model wasn't builded with CMake even though I followd pytorch document

Comment: The CUDA version reported by `nvidia-smi` is the *maximum* CUDA version supported by the installed driver package (of which `nvidia-smi` is a part). You can certainly run CUDA 11.8 or CUDA 12.1 with this driver. You **cannot** run CUDA 12.3 (the latest version available) with the installed driver.

Comment: OMG, Thanks a lot! It was the maximum. then, I just install the latest nvidia driver and be able to choose the CUDA version that I want!?

Comment: @ Re "I just install the latest nvidia driver and be able to choose the CUDA version that I want?" Within reason, yes. The latest CUDA driver may have dropped support for older hardware that was still supported in older CUDA versions.